# Over the Edge... Only Not

Tags: over-the-edge

Is anyone using Atlas Games' Over the Edge for anything besides the standard Al Amarja campaign?

Answer (score 4):

Over the Edge is a fairly simple system for larger than life characters, and so I've used it for several pulp games.

The system, with its broad phrase orientated game lends itself to characters that have a bucket they are good at, but those buckets are fairly well defined. This has always struck me as working really well with games where we have characters with an identity (flying ace, intrepid reporter, gumshoe) that marks them but can incorporate different things based on the need of the story.

My favorite was a Williams S Burrough's *Cities of the Red Night* inspired game.

Answer (score 3):

I used it for an In Nomine campaign.  I liked the In Nomine setup but the system made me sad. Although I did use Al Amarja - I passed around a rumor that God and the Devil couldn't "see" anything that happened on AA for some strange reason, so angels that wanted to do something bad or vice versa could get away with it there.

That was some time ago, however.